# java.util.Date is not supported

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to write `RDD` to `MYSQL`, which `RDD` contains `java.util.Date` type.

```
rdd.map(f=> FeatureData(
           f.get("name").toString, 
           f.get("value").toString.toDouble, 
           f.get("time").asInstanceOf[Date],
           f.get("period").toString))
    .toDF()
```

In this `RDD` the key of `time`'s value type is also `java.util.Date` and it just get the error of 
`[See nested exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type java.util.Date is not supported`

Comment: Try converting it into `java.sql.Date`

Comment: If I set  `f.get("time").asInstanceOf[java.sql.Date]`, It will get the error that `java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date`

Comment: You cannot cast it directly, but once you have a sql.Date you can instantiate a util.Date manually reading from the sql.Date fields

Comment: Thank you, it works.  `new java.sql.Date( f.get("time").asInstanceOf[java.util.Date].getTime )`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

At first convert **java.util.Date** to **java.sql.Date**. Then run your sql with the data of **java.sql.Date**. Sample code :

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

**Update:**
AndreHolzner suggested to use `java.sql.Timestamp`. I did not try it yet, but generally `Timestamp` is better than `Date`.

Comment: I'd rather use `java.sql.Timestamp` since `java.sql.Date` seems to have day granularity (i.e. ignores time of the day) on my system

Comment: @AndreHolzner, Thank you for your suggestion.I will update answer.