# Using java.util.date in a spark Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to Join two spark dataset to have one dataset in result.
my first dataset is created from a java bean class generated from Cassandra database :

this is my java bean, and I'm not allowed to edit it :

```
public class IdCellSynchro implements Serializable {
 @PartitionKey
 @Column
 private Long id_cell;
 @Column
 private Date last_synchro_date; 
 @Column
 private Date last_request_data_date; }
```

And the Dataset is created like this :

```
Dataset<IdCellSynchro> dSTileCells = sparkSession.createDataset(tile.getCellPoints(), encoder);   
Encoder<IdCellSynchro> encoder = Encoders.bean(IdCellSynchro.class);
Dataset<Row> dFTileCells = dSTileCells.toDF();
```

Once the dataset created, the Date fields are in a struct format like this :

```
|-- last_request_data_date: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- date: integer (nullable = false)
|    |-- day: integer (nullable = false)
|    |-- hours: integer (nullable = false)
|    |-- minutes: integer (nullable = false)
|    |-- month: integer (nullable = false)
|    |-- seconds: integer (nullable = false)
|    |-- time: long (nullable = false)
|    |-- timezoneOffset: integer (nullable = false)
|    |-- year: integer (nullable = false)
```

and the content is pretty weird :

```
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------+
|    id_cell|last_request_data_date|last_synchro_date|
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------+
|70013300261|  [26,15,24,5,39,10...|             null|
|70013300262|  [26,15,24,5,39,10...|             null|
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

I tried to get ll the fields of this structure by using withColumn function to make my own format but it does not correspond to the correct date.

```
+---------+-----+---+----+-----+-------+----------+----+--------------+
|     year|month|day|date|hours|minutes|   seconds|time|timezoneOffset|
+---------+-----+---+----+-----+-------+----------+----+--------------+
|536879861|   39| 15|  26|   24|      5|1018322500| 118|             1|
|536879861|   39| 15|  26|   24|      5|1018322501| 118|             1|
+---------+-----+---+----+-----+-------+----------+----+--------------+
```

The goal is to use this Date field to do à Join with a second dataset, loaded from a Parquet, where a Date field is a dateTime with a standard format : |2018-05-01 00:00:00|

have you any idea to handle this kind of date (java.util.date) with spark.

Comment: Have you tried using `java.sql.Date` instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312108/java-util-date-is-not-supported

Comment: Hello Dan, I tried already this solution by modifying the format of the dates directly in my javaBean but the link with my database was not made. i'm going to create my datatset from a full string structure made from my java bean.